# How to run a gps in background service for ever 15 mins using service?

Tags: android, gps, android-service

Hello am new for android development what my need is need to fetch user location for ever 15 mins and send to server i learned i can be done with using service. After the implementation when i clear the app from recent memory i stop updating i read and tried all solution how can i achieve this even when recent app is cleared need to make sure my service is running and fetching the user location let me post my service code:

```
public class GPSService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 10000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
                super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent("restartApps");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

My broadcast receiver :

```
public class RestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "RestartService";

    public RestartService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, GPSService.class));
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="precisioninfomatics.backgroundgps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:name=".gspapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".GPS"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyLocationService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".GPSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".RestartService"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="restartApps" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Problems are:

**1. Need to fetch user location even after clear my recent app
   2. if user force stop in settings how to restart my service**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

start service with START_STICKY service so that if it is killed because of some priority than it's recreate and if you want to continuously run this service in background and WAKE_Lock that service and using Alarm Manager check it is runnig or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager to schedule your service. Something like:

```
AlarmManager alarm =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent checkLocationIntent = new Intent(context, CheckLocationService.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, checkLocationIntent, 0);

    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, ALARM_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS,
            ALARM_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS, pendingIntent);
```

This will run the CheckLocationService every ALARM_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS time